# Pasar una Variable Controlador a la Vista y como usarlo

Tags: laravel-5

tengo una duda como pasar la Variable $info_pago de un controlador para ser usada en la vista checkout  y como trabajar en ella.

```
$info_pago = [
      'merchantId' => "508029",
      'accountId' =>'512321',
      'description' => 'Online Store',
      'referenceCode' => $reference_code,
      'amount' => Cart::total(),
      'signature'=> md5($api_key."~"."508029"."~"."XXXX01"."~". Cart::total() )
  ];

  return view('checkout', ['info_pago' => $info_pago ]);
```

No se como poder utilizarlo para un formulario, pensaba aalgo asi.. .

```
<input name="merchantId"    type="hidden"  value="{{ request()->merchantId }}" >
              <input name="accountId"     type="hidden"  value="{{ $info_pago->accountId }}" >
              <input name="description"   type="hidden"  value="{{ $info_pago->description }}" >
              <input name="referenceCode" type="hidden"  value="{{ $info_pago->referenceCode}}" >
              <input name="amount"        type="hidden"  value="{{ $info_pago->amount }}"   >
```

Agradezco la aclaraciòn..

Answer (score 0):

Para pasar una variable del controlador a la vista basta con poner lo siguiente:

```
return View::make('checkout')->with('info_pago', $info_pago);
```

Donde `checkout` es la vista, `'info_pago'` el nombre con el que lo llamarás en la vista y `$info_pago` la variable que le quieras pasar.

Para mostrarlo en la vista se hace de la manera que muestras en tu pregunta:

```
 <p>{{ $info_pago->accountId }}</p>
```